# Get full html for large tables (formattable package)

Tags: r, formattable

I have a table with 300 rows I'd like to get html code for. When I create the table in R Studio using format_table I am returned only part of the html code to copy paste as it appears the console limit prevents the full code from showing. How exactly can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

One option to create a nice html table (widget) is the datatable() .function from DT

```
library(DT)

datatable(iris)
```

or use :

```
htmlTable::htmlTable(iris)
```

for a more basic html table